# How to stop bach of jobs posted to TPL pipeline using Polly

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, polly

I am exploring different ways how to implement `TPL DataFlow` pipeline.  Please follow code sample with all the comments to understand my question. Here are two simple blocks:

```
//DataClass is very simple class with two properties int Id, and enum Status
var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<DataClass, DataClass>((data) =>
{
    //Here I use Polly library to help with retrying when exception has occured
    //I have chosen to retry only on WebException, because in this case there is 
    //no need to try ObjectNotFoundException
    var policy = Policy.Handle<WebException>().WaitAndRetry(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    try
    {
        policy.Execute(() =>
        {
            //ThisMethodMyThrowWebException();
            data.Status = Status.Completed;
        });
    }
    catch (ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        data.Status = Status.Failed;
        //Notify user that object is not found;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        data.Status = Status.Failed;
        //I would like to cancel whole batch of jobs that were sent to pipeline.
    }
    return data;
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });


var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<DataClass>((data) =>
{
    if (data.Status != Status.Failed)
    {
        //Do something with data
    }
});

downloadBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock);
```

Lets say there is a large amount of items pushed into the pipeline and permanent error has occured. It would take a while till all items would run through their retries without any success. Instead I would like to stop processing them when certain retry count threshold is reached. To achieve this I could pass `CancellationTokenSource` to each `Block` but my goal is to create pipeline that would be alive till my app is terminated. As far I know, if I cancel the `Block` my pipeline is gone. Of course I could pass token to delegate inside `Execute()` but that would only stop inside processing methods. Any ideas on how to achieve this using Polly library?

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding something because I am a bit confused. Do you want the pipeline to stop processing incoming messages after a specific number of errors, but still be alive for the whole lifetime of the application? Aren't these requirements contradictory?

Comment: @Theodor Ummh..well, kind of, but I don't want to stop the pipeline from accepting new future incoming items. I would like to stop or cancel only items that are already sent to pipeline and keep pipeline alive if possible. Hope I made it more clear.

Comment: Regarding the number of errors that will trigger the cancellation of the currently buffered items, how do you count the errors of a `Polly.WaitAndRetry` policy that failed after 3 attempts? Is this one error or three?

Comment: @Theodor I suppose it would be easier to count it as one error.

Comment: Hi Niks. Could you elaborate why passing a token to the delegates is not a good solution to the problem? It seems to me that it should work quite well. When the number of errors has been reached, cancel the old `CancellationTokenSource` and create a new one, and reset the counter of the errors.

Comment: @niks Can you please share with us a sample worst case scenario? Like: 1) Data #1 goes into the `downloadBlock` 2) It fails after 5 seconds 3) A 1 second delay has been used as penalty 4) New attempt is being made ... n+1) final attempt fails. What should then happen?

Comment: @Theodor Yes, you are right, I can put `CancelationToken` right into `Execute` like this: `policy.Execute(p =>{//ThisMethodMyThrowWebException()}, cts.Token);` I made a false assumption I could only pass token into delagate method itself (ThisMethodMyThrowWebException that is) and my program would run `Execute` all remaining retries for all items just to cancel inside method. What a dumb mistake:/ I feel very stupid now. If any of you wants to post this as an actual answer, I would gladly accept it. Maybe this can be useful for somebody else as well.

Comment: @Peter Please, check my previous comment. I am sorry for confusion.

Comment: Niks I am not too familiar with the Polly library, so I'll skip writing an answer. I suggest that you answer the question yourself, now that you have the details fresh in your memory. Btw answering one's own question is quite common and [well received](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

With the help in comment section I came to conclusion that answer is rather simple - I just have to pass `CancellationToken` into `policy.Execute()` method like this:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
policy.Execute(p =>
{
    //ThisMethodMyThrowWebException();
    data.Status = Status.Completed;
}, cts.Token);
```

---

**EDIT:**
Based on request from other users I am updating my answer with full code sample that tries to answer questions in comment section.

It is a bit lengthy, but in order to tackle `OperationCancelledException` I needed to come up with logic how to distinguish between exception that is thrown from method (and therefore should be retried) and the one that is thrown because user has decided to cancel job.

I also decided to include additional code with `CircuitBreaker` because without it this answer would be incomplete in my opinion. So here we go!

```
private TransformBlock<ConstructData, ConstructData> _downloadBlock;
private AsyncCircuitBreakerPolicy _circuitBreaker;
//This flag will indicate to circuitBreaker and catch block
//that OperationCanceledException was induced by user and 
//therefore it should not be looked upon as worthy by circuitBreaker
//to decide when to open circuit.
private bool _downloadCanceledByUser;
private CancellationTokenSource _downloadCts;
private void CreatePipeline()
{
    var failedItemQueue = new Queue<ConstructData>();

    _circuitBreaker
        = Policy.Handle<WebException>()
                .Or<OperationCanceledException>(ex => !_downloadCanceledByUser)
                .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromDays(5),
                 (exception, timespan) => { },
                 () =>
                 {
                     while (failedItemQueue.Count > 0)
                     {
                         _downloadBlock.Post(failedItemQueue.Dequeue());
                     }
                 });

    var retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<WebException>().Or<OperationCanceledException>()
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(2, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    #region DownloadBlock
    _downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<ConstructData, ConstructData>(async (construct) =>
    {
        var downloadPolicy = retryPolicy.WrapAsync(circuitBreaker);
        try
        {
            await downloadPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async fp =>
            {
                //await MethodThatMayThrowWebException(_downloadCts.Token);
                //await MethodThatMayThrowOperationCanceledException(_downloadCts.Token);
                construct.Status = DownloadFileStatus.Downloaded;
            }, _downloadCts.Token);
        }

        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            construct.Status = DownloadFileStatus.Failed;
            //Here after 2 failed retries guaranteed by retryPolicy,
            //I repost failed item back to the queue. 
            _downloadBlock.Post(construct);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            construct.Status = DownloadFileStatus.Canceled;
            //In case if OperationCanceledException was thrown from 
            //MethodThatMayThrowOperationCanceledException()
            //item gets posted back to downloadBlock for retry.
            if (!_downloadCanceledByUser)
                _downloadBlock.Post(construct);
        }
        //When total exception count reaches circuitBreaker threshold, circuit is left in open state
        catch (BrokenCircuitException ex)
        {
            //TODO Notify user that he needs to check internet connection and press reload.
            construct.Status = DownloadFileStatus.Failed;
            failedItemQueue.Enqueue(construct);
        }
        return construct;
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });
    #endregion DownloadBlock

    #region ProcessBlock

    var processBlock = new ActionBlock<ConstructData>(construct =>
    {
        if (construct.Status == DownloadFileStatus.Downloaded)
        {
            var fullName = string.Concat(construct.Path, construct.Name);
            try
            {
                //ProcessingMethod(_downloadCts.Token);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                //TODO Do logging if needed.
            }
        }
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 });
    #endregion

    _downloadBlock.LinkTo(processBlock);
}

public void PushDataIntoPipeline(List<ConstructData> data)
{
    //Reset properties if previous batch was canceled
    if (_downloadCanceledByUser)
    {
        _downloadCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _downloadCanceledByUser = false;
    }
    //Push data into pipeline
    _ = data.Select(downloadBlock.SendAsync).ToList();
}
public void CancelData()
{
    _downloadCanceledByUser = true;
    _downloadCts.Cancel();
}
public void Reload()
{
    _circuitBreaker.Reset();
}
```

Comment: This is just part of the story. Please share with the community the whole code of `downloadBlock` and `actionBlock`. Because there are couple of unanswered questions like: When do call `Cancel`? How do you tackle `OperationCanceledException`? etc..

Comment: @Peter. Yes, I will finish my code and update the answer!;)

Comment: @Peter Hi, Peter, I edited my answer. Please, take a look at it if you have such a wish and time. You will most definitely find some flaws with my approach.

Comment: Quite frankly, even though your code is not so large but it's hard to flow. If you ask for code review then please use [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) not StackOverflow for that purpose.